# GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling

Tags: jenkins

I configured hooktrigger job with set of pre-defined steps
1.Installed Git and Git hub
2.Jenkins URL http://localhost:8080/jenkins (Running inside Apache)
3.Mentioned Git path in configure section C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
4.Added GitHub URL https://github.com/sanveen/HelloWorldJSP.git with Git hub credentials in job configuration
5.In github added http://localhost:8080/jenkins/hooktrigger/ as jenkins hooks URL

when i commit and pushed the code to repository, nothing happened. Seeing msg in Github as "Last delivery was not successful. Could not connect to server.

Please help to resolve on this

Comment: Your Jenkins server must be publicly accessible. Localhost will not work.

Comment: Could  you help me how to make it?

Comment: Can anyone help how to make jenkin server publicly accessible

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/526899/how-to-make-my-ip-publicly-accessible-to-make-my-local-tomcat-server-public

Comment: There are a number of ways to make your Jenkins instance publicly accessible, but it depends on where you have installed it, your network, your ISP, etc. There are too many details involved and they are beyond the scope of the Jenkins tag.